# Authenticated download with Inno Setup

Tags: http, installation, inno-setup, inno-download-plugin

I have files on my HTTP server which should be downloaded.
I can properly download them from usual HTTP-server, but my server asks for authorization during download (this download should be protected).

How can I include login/password information to exe-file or to force Inno Setup to show authorization window to user?

Because now Inno Setup just shows me error window: *access denied*, with no possibility to enter login/password.

I'm using Inno Download Plugin for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `idpSetLogin` function to set the credentials:

```pascal
procedure idpSetLogin(login, password: String);                
  external 'idpSetLogin@files:idp.dll cdecl';
```

---

If you want to query the user for the credentials, you can use [`CreateInputQueryPage` support function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputquerypage).